# Is their a way to have the child class use the variables created in the parent class?

Tags: java, parent-child

I have a child class to handle images dragged onto the screen. It stores the name, and x, y position of each image in variables. Then it has a methods to scale them and do other operations.

I would like to have 2 of these classes, but the image name and x, y position would be different.

I first tried to create a class that has this class as a child class. In this parent class, I tried creating the same variables, hoping it would use these, instead of the ones created in the child class.

The child class still used the variables created within it, instead of in the parent.

Is there a way to do this, or am I climbing up the wrong tree?

```
public class cShapeParent extends cShapes {

    // would like the base class to use this data
    String[] mNames=
    {
        "ball_green.png",
        "ball_green.png",
        "ball_green.png"    
    };

    cShapeParent(Context context,int screenWidth, int screenHeight)
    {
        super(context, screenWidth, screenHeight);
    }
}
```

Child class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Rect;

public class cShapes {
    public 

    String[] mNames=
    {
        "ball_green.png",
        "ball_red.png",
        "ball_blue.png" 
    };

    int[] mX={200,300,400};
    int[] mY={200,200,200};
    int[] mW={0,0,0};
    int[] mH={0,0,0};

    int Amount=3;
    int MyScreenWidth=512;

    int[] BitMapId={ 
        R.drawable.ball_green,  R.drawable.ball_red,
        R.drawable.ball_blue,  R.drawable.ball_green
    };

    Bitmap MyImages[];
    Rect[] mBitmapSize;

    cShapes(Context context,int screenWidth, int screenHeight)
    {
        // Load in bitmaps
        MyImages=new Bitmap[4];

        AssetManager assetManager= context.getAssets();
        InputStream inputStream;
        mBitmapSize = new Rect[Amount];
        try {
            // set scaling ratio
            float r=(float)MyScreenWidth / (float)screenWidth;
            for(int i=0;i<Amount;i++)
            {
                inputStream=assetManager.open( mNames[i]);
                MyImages[i]=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);

                int w=(int)( (float)MyImages[i].getWidth()*r);
                int h=(int)( (float)MyImages[i].getWidth()*r);
                mBitmapSize[i]=new Rect(0,0,w,h);
                mW[i]=w; mH[i]=h;

                mX[i]=(int) ( (float)mX[i]*r);
                mY[i]=(int) ( (float)mY[i]*r);

                inputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
    }

    boolean Intersect(int id, int x,int y)
    {
        if ( x >= mX[id] && x <= mX[id]+128 && y >= mY[id] && y <= mY[id]+128 ) 
            return true;

        return false;
    }
}  // end class
```

Comment: I just can't bring myself to edit the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, you want to access the variables defined in your super class from your sub class. If thats your question then yes, its possible using super keyword.

```
class Super{
public int i;
}
class Sub extends Super {
   public void method() {
    System.out.println(super.i); // you can access i as it is overriden by sub
   } 
}
```

Note that, you can access `i` directly even without the **super** keyword, i just included it to make it more expressive. However, you can only access `i` in this example when its not declared as `private`.

Comment: You don't even _need_ to use `super` in this example, do you?

Comment: @Madbreaks notr really, but its bit expressive :)

Comment: Agreed, but thought it warranted some explanation (which I see you did, nice).  +1

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR your _expressive_ (?) username is making me sea-sick, by the way

Answer (score 0):

Wait, Are you wanting the Child (`cShapeParent`) class to create and hold onto variables that the Parent (`cShapes`) class can reference? In which case I would follow this sort of pattern:

```
public class Child extends Parent {

    private String[] mNames= {
    "ball_green.png",
    "ball_red.png",
    "ball_blue.png" 
    };

    protected String[] getNames() {
        return mNames;
    }

}

public abstract class Parent {

    protected abstract ListString[] getNames();

    public void doX() {
        ...
        String[] names = getNames();
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for the help, I'm sort of learning Java as I program my apps.

Comment: @Tedpottel Glad I could help! Something else you may look at, instead of having parallel arrays for all the details of your images, create a simple wrapper that can hold onto the details of a single image. That way you can pass a list of those around :) (also the Collections APIs can be nicer to work with over arrays, in many cases anyways)